# After calling fclose(), how quickly will the file be available to another thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, fopen

I have an application that runs on Windows and Linux. It creates a file, writes to it, and calls fclose(). After some indeterminate time, the name of the file is sent another thread. The other thread opens the file using fopen() and reads its contents.

One user is reporting the application fails on Debian 6 unless he creates a short delay before opening the file.

When fclose() is called and returns, how quickly will the file be available to other threads through fopen()?

Comment: Did you consider using sync() after closing, on Linux?

Comment: Need more details to answer: (1) are these threads in the same process?  (2) Who is sending the name of the file?  (Is it the thread that called fclose()?  (3) What is the "failure"?

Comment: I presume you at least have some kind of thread locking mechanism in place around your file I/O code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, so I'll try to answer several interpretations.

If your question is how soon after `fclose` it's *possible* to `fopen` the file again, the answer is simply that it's possible *any time*, even before `fclose`. POSIX does not permit file opens to be mutually exclusive; it's possible to open a file as many times as you like as long as you don't hit the system open-file limits. Even if you're on a non-conforming platform like Windows with a pseudo-POSIX-threads implementation, as long as the `fopen` is ordered after the `fclose`, you're fine, because the underlying close operation must complete before `fclose` can return.

If your concern on the other hand is about availability of the data written by one thread for reading by another thread, then as long as you can establish a "happens-before" relationship between the flush (either explicitly via `fflush` or as part of the `fclose` operation) that wrote the data and the reads elsewhere, you're fine. Any pthread synchronization functions such a use of a mutex, or `pthread_join`, would be sufficient to establish this relationship.

Answer (score -1):

fclose() is provided by libc hence the implementation could vary on different platforms/OSs and I doubt if there's a way to detect the availability of the file after fclose() is fired and returned. Maybe you can set up a parameter of the delay and tune it for different clients.

Comment: -1 for guessing and for suggesting the bogus idiom of "data synchronization via sleep".